# autojoin Yammer External Network

Tags: networking, external, yammer

I have created a Yammer External Network and I want every one to join automatically I do have admin for all user on yammer enterprise

please help if possible

Thanks,
Yousef

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add users to your external network automatically. If you are the Admin, you can invite your users in bulk from **Settings > Network Admin > Invite Users**.

Or if you have the Yammer's Premium account, you can directly add users from **Settings > Network Admin > Bulk Update**.
You would need to provide your users in .csv format.
Within the Bulk Update User page, you can add, update, suspend or delete users. You’ll need to format your .CSV as a table